# Getting LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException though mvn is installed

Tags: maven, terminal, installation, osx-yosemite

I have installed maven manually through my Mac's(OS- Yosemite) terminal. 
The command  `mvn -version`

gives the below output:

```
> Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06;
> 2015-04-22T17:27:37+05:30)  Maven home:
> /Users/shilpa_rajendran/Documents/basicsoft/apache-maven-3.3.3 Java
> version: 1.7.0_71, vendor: Oracle Corporation  Java home:
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
> Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8  OS name: "mac os x",
> version: "10.10.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

But when I do `mVn clean` , I am getting the below:

> [ERROR] Could not create local repository at
>   /Users/shilpa_rajendran/.m2/repository -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To
>   see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug
>   logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and
>   possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help
>   1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was a m2 file which was already present in the location where the .m2 folder gets created usually. Just delete the folder and run your mvn command again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your path is not set properly for .m2 folder.

```
Could not create local repository at /Users/shilpa_rajendran/.m2/repository -> [Help 1]
This is showing that not particular path is found to access or create .m2 folder in Maven.

Step 1) Goto .m2 folder and find setting.xml file
Step 2) Open with administrator cmd (WINDOWS)/ sudo command (LINUX).
Step 3) Open Setting.xml file
Step 4) Find <local-reposirtory>
Step 5) You can see your current path : **/Users/shilpa_rajendran/.m2/repository** .
Step 6) Change that path to current .m2 folder location path.
```

Thanks
vishal